# Number of fixed points of generators of reflections (Coxeter) group

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, combinatorial-group-theory, coxeter-groups

Say I have a group with presentation like

$$\langle s,t,u \mid s^2,t^2,u^2,(st)^2,(su)^3,(ut)^4\rangle,$$

faithful on set $S$ with exactly one orbit ($|S|$ is known). How could I determine $|\text{Fix}(s)|$, the number of elements fixed by $s$ (equivalently, how many transpositions produce s)? If necessary, suppose I know $|\text{Fix}((st)^n)|$ for all pairs of the generators and for all $n$.

For example, say |S| = 6, and:

- $|\text{Fix}(st)|$ = 0
- $|\text{Fix}(su)|$ = 0
- $|\text{Fix}(tu)|$ = 2

I know that $st$ must be composed of 3 2-cycles (3 transpositions), $su$ is composed of 2 3-cycles (4 transpositions), and $ut$ is composed of 1 4-cycle (3 transpositions). Since $s$, $t$, and $u$ have order 2, they must be products of disjoint transpositions. Therefore, $$|\text{Transpositions}(s)| + |\text{Transpositions}(t)| \geq 3 $$
$$|\text{Transpositions}(s)| + |\text{Transpositions}(u)| \geq 4 $$
$$|\text{Transpositions}(u)| + |\text{Transpositions}(t)| \geq 3 $$
where ${\rm Transpositions}(\sigma)$ is the number of transpositions needed to produce $\sigma$. If you can solve that then
$$|\text{Fix}(s)| = n - 2\cdot|\text{Transpositions}(s)|$$
I doubt those thoughts help but that’s as far as I’ve gotten that I’m sure about.

Comment: Please check the relations. I suspect one of them could be about the power of $tu$. I'm not sure about the actual question as the group can act on many kinds of set. May be something general can be said? Basically you seem to want to reproduce the action from knowing the number of fixed points for powers of a single element?

Comment: Oh, you seem to mean that the fixed points of powers of $su$ and $tu$ are also known, can you clarify?

Comment: You were right about that typo. And yes, I know the number of fixed points of st, su, and tu. I want to know the number of fixed points for s, t and u. I also know the order of S.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can deduce this from the information given.

For example, take the vertices of the truncated cube as $S$:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_cube

It has the symmetry you described, none of the rotations $st$, $su$ or $tu$ fix any of its vertices, but there are certain reflections (6 out of 9) that keep 4 vertices fixed.

If you take $S$ to be (the vertices of) two concentric truncated cubes of different sizes, you would have $|S|=48$ and

- $|\mathrm{Fix}(st)^k|=0$ $(k<2)$
- $|\mathrm{Fix}(su)^k|=0$ $(k<3)$
- $|\mathrm{Fix}(tu)^k|=0$ $(k<4)$

Similarly, if you take $S$ to be (the vertices of) the truncated cuboctahedron: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_cuboctahedron

You would have exactly the same situation ($|S|=48$ and no vertices fixed by rotations). However, for the truncated cubes you have $|\mathrm{Fix}(s)|=8$ and for the truncated cuboctahdron you have $|\mathrm{Fix}(s)|=0$.

Comment: In the example I gave, we know that one of the rotations does fix 2 vertices, but you contradict this in your second paragraph. Also, you are forgetting that one of the reflections of a Cuboctahedron does have $|\text{Fix}(s)|=8$, so there is no contradiction with the truncated cubes.

Comment: By the way, in your second paragraph you say there are 9 reflections in the symmetry I described, but remember I only care about the 3 generators.

Comment: A cuboctahedron is not a truncated cube.  I chose a truncated cube instead of a cuboctahedron because a truncated cube does not have any vertices fixes by rotations, whereas a cuboctahedron does.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant to say that one of the (generators) reflections of a truncated cuboctahedron does have |Fix()|=8, just like for the concentric truncated cubes, so I don't believe there is a contradiction.

Comment: no, there is no reflection of a truncated cuboctahedron that has $|\mathrm{Fix}(s)|=8$. The octahedral symmetry group acts freely on the vertices of a truncated cuboctahedron, so $|\mathrm{Fix}(\sigma)|=0$ for every non-identity element $\sigma\in O_h$.

Comment: I may be wrong, but while it may be true that the $O$ acts freely on the vertices of a truncated cuboctahedron, I don't think that this is the case for $O_h$. Look at this diagram: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Full_octahedral_group_elements_in_truncated_cuboctahedron;_numbers.svg . Imagine a reflection plane through 15 and 17. Already we have two fixed points, but since the plane intersects the origin, 15' and 17' should also be included. I think that 11', 11, 21, and 21' should also be fixed, making 8.

Comment: this reflection plane would switch around the two polygons on both sides of the edge 15--17. those are an octahedron and a hexagon, these cannot be swapped around

Comment: You're definitely right, but I suppose I would then ask the same question again with the condition that the set have only one orbit under the group action. Do you think that is a solvable problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not; Either the truncated cube, truncated octahedron or (small) rhombicuboctahedron has 24 vertices and none of these fixed by rotations. Truncated cube and rhombicuboctahedron both have |Fix($s$)|=|Fix($u$)|=4 and |Fix($t$)|=0, but truncated octahedron has |Fix($s$)|=|Fix($u$)|=0 and |Fix($t$)|=8.

Answer (score 1):

So the question is a little ambiguous as to whether it’s really about *this particular example* or whether it’s about *general problems of this form*, illustrated with one particular example.  In the latter case, the right answer is probably "go read about $G$-sets and the representation theory of finite groups".

In the former case, the size 6 is so small that it’s quite possible there is a unique answer.  There is at least one natural model: the symmetry group of the cube acting on its faces (equiv: octahedron, vertices).  It would be very easy to ask a computer to check if there are others, but maybe the size is even small enough to do by hand.  In particular: you know $st$ up to conjugacy in $S_6$, so fix a choice, say $st \mapsto (123)(456)$ without loss of generality.  We have 15 choices of a fixed point-free involution $su$ (and, incidentally, note that these two elements together will already be transitive necessarily), many of which are the same up to conjugacy by the commutator of the chosen image of $st$.  Since $tu = (st)^{-1} \cdot (tu)$, you can easily check whether each possible $su$ image is consistent with the given information (that product should either be a four-cycle or two two-cycles).

Once you've chosen $su$ and $st$, the choice of $s$ determines the whole group.  A priori there are $15 + 45 + 15 + 1$ options (all the elements with order dividing $2$), but in fact since $t = s \cdot (st)$ also has to have order dividing $2$, your options for $s$ are super limited: try to convince yourself that the only way you can get a product of two elements of order dividing $2$ can multiply to $(123)(456)$ is if you factor the two three-cycles as a product of two transpositions separately and pair up, so the two factors have cycle type $2^2 1^2$, and there are really only $9$ choices for $s$.  Each of these nine choices either does or does not give an element $u = s \cdot (su)$ of order $2$.  And then at the end of the day you see what you've got.

(On reflection, if I were really going to do this by hand, I might choose $s$ before $su$ -- having only fixed $st$, we could actually take $s = (12)(34)$ without loss of generality.)